# Find +5 and -5 value of a Range input

Tags: jquery, html

I should be able to do this, but I need some help.

Can you help me display the -5 and +5 values of a range value?

Here are examples ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Ek9/) / [non-fiddle](http://mikemilla.com/range-adjustment)) running the code below.

```
$(function(){
    //Range
    var val     = $('#slider').val();
        output  = $('#output');

    output.html(val);

    $('#slider').on('change', function(){
        output.html(this.value);
    });
});
```

Please and thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "-5 and +5 values"?

Comment: That's _literally_ writing `val + 5` and `val - 5` ...

Comment: @Blazemonger The range value +/- 5 as an example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a number to another number in JavaScript](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Comment: He wants all the numbers in between too I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:
jQuery changed:

```
       $('#slider').on('change', function(){
            output.html(this.value);
            $('#prev-output').html(parseInt(this.value)-5);
            $('#next-output').html(parseInt(this.value)+5);
        });
```

html changed:

```
        <div id="measurement">
            <span id="prev-output"></span> (<span id="output"></span>) <span id="next-output"></span>
        </div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F3Ek9/1/)

Comment: Glad to help you! Remind to accept the answer hen you can to hlp other guys with your same problem @MikeMilla

Comment: Yessir, gotta wait 5 more minutes then I will! Thanks again! Good to know there are actually kind people on this site :)